# How to make my loop still run correctly if the data type of entered variable is not as same as its before?

Tags: c++

I got this problem while I was coding an exercise from my teacher. I tried to enter the 'IDcheck' as a character or string but the line: 'You entered the wrong ID, please try again: ' looped infinitely so I want it stopped and start from the beginning. What would I do now? Please help me,thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int ID = 123;
const int password = 123456;

int IDcheck, passwordcheck;

cout << "Enter the ID: "; cin >> IDcheck; cout << endl;

do
{
    cout << "You entered the wrong ID, please try again: ";
    cin >> IDcheck;
    cout << endl;
} while (ID != IDcheck);

cout << "Enter the password: "; cin >> passwordcheck; cout << endl;

do
{
    cout << "You entered the wrong password, please try again: ";
    cin >> passwordcheck;
    cout << endl;
} while (password != passwordcheck);

cout << "Welcome to my world!" << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read the whole line into a string, then either put that string into an `istringstream` and use that stream to extract the values, or use `std::stoi`.

Comment: im not familiar with `c++` but assuming its like most other languages you need to put the `enter your ID` line inside the `do while` loop

Answer (score 1):

A `do { ... } while (...)` will always run, the test is performed at the end of the loop. A `while (...) { ... }` *might* run, the test is performed before each round starts.

Consider using a straight `while` loop if you want it to loop if and only if you make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are using do { statement(s); }while( condition ) but in your code no need for do while loop. In do { statement(s); }while( condition ) Notice that the conditional expression appears at the end of the loop, so the statement(s) in the loop execute once before the condition is tested.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
        {
        const int ID = 123;
        const int password = 123456;
        int IDcheck, passwordcheck;
        cout << "Enter the ID: "; cin >> IDcheck; cout << endl;

        while (ID != IDcheck);
        {
            if(ID != IDcheck)
              {
             cout << "You entered the wrong ID, please try again: ";
              }
         else {
            cout << "Enter the ID: "; cin >> IDcheck; cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
              }
        } 

        cout << "Enter the password: "; cin >> passwordcheck; cout << endl;

        while (password != passwordcheck);
        {
            if((password != passwordcheck)
              {
            cout << "You entered the wrong password, please try again: ";
              }
         else {
            cout << "Enter the password: "; cin >> passwordcheck; cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
             }
        } 

        cout << "Welcome to my world!" << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know my code doesn't need a do-while loop but the point is when I enter into 'IDcheck' a string then my program keeps running, infinitely.

Comment: Use isdigit() function. chechk the following tutorial.                                                  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEbMhE7ARvw

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while(..){..}` loop because a `do{...}while(...)` loop runs for at least one time regardless of the condition moreover the loop will only terminate if you enter the id `123` so if you try to enter a string which is not `"123"` the loop will go on infinitely. Also, the type of `IDCheck` is defined as `int` so if you enter a string containing alphabets the value of `IDcheck` will change to the first integer part of the string.
For example if you enter 12ab, value of `IDCheck` will set to 12.